# Keyword association to contact number

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I need help with Marketing Cloud MobileConnect.
Is it possible to link a keyword and a ShortCode to a contact number per REST API?

I found the example below in the documentation, but it does not work.

Example QueueMO API Request

```
POST https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/sms/v1/queueMO
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN
{
  "mobileNumbers": [
    "15555551212"
  ],
  "shortCode": "Code",
  "messageText": "KEYWORD"
}
```

[Mobile Connect API documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/using-the-mobileconnect-api.htm)

Comment: do you have the message for that keyword setup as a mobile opt-in?

Comment: Hello @EazyE

Yes, I have the message.
My method is as follows:
`
{
  "mobileNumbers": [
    "5541998782415"
  ],
  "shortCode": "38383",
  "messageText": "ATILE"
}
`

I get the feedback as positive

{
    "results": [
        {
            "identifier": "SUhvMkkzSmV5a21aOU8tV3NsNTFsUTo3Njow",
            "mobileNumber": "5541998782415",
            "result": "OK"
        }
    ]
}


But the keyword is not associated with the number.

Comment: If you text ATILE from that mobile number do you get a response?

Comment: @EazyE

I do not receive the message

Comment: have you created an optin message and assigned it to this keyword?